# Wordpress Custom Search By Alphabet and order by asc and sesc

Tags: theme-development, search, sql

I am new to word-press but i can easily work on core php and other mvc framework,acutally i want to add custom search for only subcategory post.
**The search will with below**

- Search post By old to new
- Search post By new to old
- Search post by Alphabet

I add the following html and php code inside archive.php of theme

```
<form action="" method="post" class="searchandfilter">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <select name="ofcategory" id="ofcategory" class="postform">
                    <option value="0">Select order...</option>
                    <option class="level-0" value="desc">Old to new</option>
                    <option class="level-0" value="asc">New to old</option>

                </select>

            </li>
            <li>
                <select name="ofpost_tag" id="ofpost_tag" class="postform">
                    <option value="0">All Tags</option>
                    <?php foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $i) {?>
                                           <option class="level-0" value="<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                                        <?php } ?>    
                </select>

            </li>
            <li>

                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

[my site link](http://khabarchar.com/category/entertainment/etymology/)

[image]

The problem is that how can i achieve this?
How i can use custom query that get search result on same page?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit of a broad question and I don't have time to hash out the whole thing, but your search code needs to modify the query something very much like:

```
add_action(
  'pre_get_posts',
  function ($qry) {
    if ($qry->is_search()) {
      $qry->set('orderby','title');
    }
  }
);
```

I have a feeling a lot of details are missing from the question though.

Comment: @s_hum_dum where i can put this code?also how its take drop down value?